# Children element not stretch parent container

Tags: html, css, width, overflow

Children element not stretch parent container.

My code:

html:

```
<div class='window'>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <div class='short'>short</div>
        <div class='long'>long</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.window{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: gray;
}

.wrapper{
    background: pink;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.long{
    width: 700px;
    background: beige;
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/WTGAc/2/)

I want `.long` stretch his parent `.wrapper`. 
`.wrapper` width must be the same as `.long` (700px).

I can reach this by setting `float: left` to `.wrapper`.

But what happens here i don't understand, why it helps? What is the mechanism of such behavior? I need explanation, with links to w3c documentation.

What else can i do to extend `.wrapper` width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Widths and the CSS Visual Formatting Model

In you example, you have the following:

```
<div class='window'>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <div class='short'>short</div>
        <div class='long'>long</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the simplest case, `.window` is the containing block with a fixed width (500px).  The child element `.wrapper` inherits the width from `.window`.  The `.long` element has a width of 700px and it will trigger an overflow condition.  Since `.window` has `overflow: auto` declared, the `.window` element will generate a horizontal scroll bar.  Note that by using `overflow: auto`, `.window` establishes a new block formatting context, which is why the horizontal scroll bar appears on `.window` instead of the viewport/root element.

When you float `.wrapper` to the left, the `.wrapper` element defines an additional block formatting context.  A new block formatting context will ignore the width inherited from its containing block and computes a new width sufficient to enclose the content (shrink-to-fit), which is why the pink background from `.wrapper` now extends the entire 700px in width.

You can trigger the same effect by adding `position: relative` to `.window` and `position: absolute` to `.wrapper`.  However, this works because you set the height to `.window`, otherwise, the `.window` height would compute to zero since absolute elements are out of the flow and (unlike floats) will no longer affect how the `.window` content is laid out (not contribute to the height in this case).

As an aside, instead of using `float: left` on `.wrapper`, you can also try `overflow: auto` which will also establish a new block formatting context but this time the scrolling bar appears on `.wrapper` instead of `.window`.

The relevant documentation from w3.org is:

> 10 Visual formatting model details
>   10.3 Calculating widths and margins
>   10.3.5 Floating, non-replaced elements

Link:  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#float-width

Comment: thank you. I understand that i must establish new block formatting context. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting

Answer (score 3):

By default, the `.wrapper` div is inheriting the fixed width you set on `.window`.  You can float the `.wrapper` and set it's width to `auto` so the width expands without restriction to the parent.

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WTGAc/3/

**Theory:**

By default, the dimensions of `wrapper` are constained to the dimensions placed on it's parent, `.window`.

> Floated elements still live within the parameters defined by their
>   parent element, ie the width available and horizontal position. They
>   still interact with text and other elements inside that parent element
>   (or other following elements). In that respect, they are quite
>   different from absolutely positioned elements, which are removed from
>   the document flow and don't interact with other elements ... but even
>   then, if they have a positioned ancestor then they are restricted by
>   the envelope of that ancestor and will use that as the basis for
>   calculating size and dimension (although they can still be made to
>   extend or exist outside that positioned ancestor).

[Source of Quote](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?845816-Are-floated-elements-really-removed-from-normal-document-flow&s=16b4a94b5d559457139aa4f069eb2043&p=5100276&viewfull=1#post5100276)

Since the element is floated and set outside of the **normal document flow**,  it can now expand to the true width of the parent, instead of the fixed width initially defined.

Comment: good answer, but i need theoretical explanations based on documentation first.

Comment: I've provided some theory.  I'm not an expert when it comes to how CSS can manipulate DOM element structure.  From what I've found, floated elements are set outside of the **normal document flow**, which allows them to behave slightly differently from other elements in the flow.